# Onblur event fires before new dynamic input is created using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm dynamically adding text inputs to a form. The new input also receives focus. On adding an `onblur` event however the `onblur` event seems to be firing as soon as the input is added. To test this I added an alert for the `onblur` event. The alert appears, and only after clicking OK is the new input created. This happens in IE, Firefox and Opera.

The following is the code I am using. I have removed all other code to for ease of reading.

```
<head><title>""</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 1;
    function addinput () {
        var inpmaster = document.getElementById("inpMaster");
        var myinput = document.createElement("input");
        myinput.id = "myfield"+count;
        myinput.name = "myfield"+count;
        myinput.type = "text";
        myinput.onblur = alert("woot");
        inpmaster.parentNode.insertBefore(myinput,inpmaster);
        inpmaster.disabled="disabled";
        myinput.focus();
        count++;
    };
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form action="" method="post"  id="admin">
        <input id="inpMaster" type="text" name="prodDesccc" onfocus="addinput();" />
    </form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using alert("woot") to assign to onblur event instead of function(){ alert("woot") ;}. 
Change your code to:

```
function addinput () {
    var inpmaster = document.getElementById("inpMaster");
    var myinput = document.createElement("input");
    myinput.id = "myfield"+count;
    myinput.name = "myfield"+count;
    myinput.type = "text";
    myinput.onblur = function(){alert("woot");};
    inpmaster.parentNode.insertBefore(myinput,inpmaster);
    inpmaster.disabled="disabled";
    myinput.focus();
    count++;
};
```